# Problemas ao carregar DropdownList em cascata cujo campo é criado dinamicamente - Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, javascript-eventos

Estou tendo problemas ao carregar um DROPDOWNLIST que é criado dinamicamente. Ao selecionar uma FORMA DE CONTATO, preciso que o dropdownlist TIPO DE CONTATO seja carregado com as opções relacionadas. O problema é que estou criando os campos dinamicamente e quando preciso chamá-los, uso o atributo id de ambos... 
No dropdownlist FORMA DE CONTATO, criei um evento change que pega o valor do campo e faz um consulta no banco para carregar o segundo dropdownlist FORMA DE CONTATO. O problema é que o campo  dropdownlist FORMA DE CONTATO se repetirá várias vezes e o índice do id vai sendo incrementado... Eu precisava, no evento change, guardar o id    do dropdownlist FORMA DE CONTATO para fazer o load corretamente quando necessário... Ou fazer de outra mareira (Aceito sugestões). Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Grande abraço a todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="control-label lb-pf-forma-contato">Forma de Contato</label>
    <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" asp-items="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.FormasContatos" data-id="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-pf-forma-contato"><option value=""></option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="text-danger val-pf-forma-contato"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" class="control-label lb-contato-tipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
    <select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" asp-items="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosTipos" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contato-tipo"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.ContatoTipo" class="text-danger val-contato-tipo"></span>
</div>
```

IDS gerados:

- FORMA DE CONTATO - id="PessoaFisicaViewModel_PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel_0__PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel_PessoaFisicaFormaContato"
- TIPO DE CONTATO
  id="PessoaFisicaViewModel_PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel_0__PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel_ContatoTipo"

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div-contatos').on("change", ".sel-pf-forma-contato", function (e) {
            //var teste = $(this).attr("data-id");
            //alert(teste);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/pessoa-fisica-gerenciar/getContatoTipo",
                type: "POST",
                data: { pessoaFisicaFormaContato: $(this).val() },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var select = $("#contato-tipo-select");// Aqui carrega o dropdownlist TIPO DE CONTATO
                    alert(select);
                    select.empty();
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: "",
                        text: ""
                    }));
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        $.each(this, function (i, item) {
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: item.value,
                                text: item.text.toUpperCase()
                            }));
                        });
                        //select.append($('<option/>', {
                        //    value: itemData.Value,
                        //    text:  itemData.Text
                        //}));
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong call the police");
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Vc pegaria o id com `$(this).attr("id")` (jQuery) ou `this.id` (JS puro).

Comment: Aí é que tá o problema @Sam!!! Se eu tiver dois ou mais dropdownlists, os ids terão index ([0], [1], [2]...)

Comment: Ex: id="PessoaFisicaViewModel_PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel_0__PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel_ContatoTipo"...... id="PessoaFisicaViewModel_PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel_1__PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel_ContatoTipo"

Comment: Vc queria pegar o id sem os números?

Comment: Dê uma olha do print onde marquei com setas vermelhas... Ao selecionar uma opção no dropdown forma de contato, tenho que gravar de alguma forma o id do dropdown "tipo de contato" que está na mesma row... Pq se eu tiver mais que uma row não tem como carregar os registros no dropdown...

Comment: O problema é que a medida que eu crio uma nova row, o id vai mudando e sendo gerado um index para cada field... Olha o nome dos ids no print..

Comment: Pelo que entendi então é que você não sabe qual dropdown preencher ao alterar o "forma de contato" porque o id do "tipo de contato" muda a cada linha? Cada par de dropdown está numa `.row`?

Comment: Isso mesmo!!! Pensei em salvar o id do segundo combobox  no evento change do primeiro combo.... e depois usá-lo.. mas não sei fazer isso...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88902/discussion-between-sam-and-master-jr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se preocupe em pegar o elemento pelo id, que pode até ser dispensável. Você consegue pegar pela classe dentro da mesma row do dropdown que disparou o evento:

```
var select = $('#div-contatos')
             .closest(".row")
             .find(".sel-contato-tipo");
```

Answer (score 1):

amigo não sei se entendi direito mas vamos lá.

> no action desse controller:

```
public IActionResult NOMEDAVIEW()
{
    ViewBag.FormaContatos = new SelectList(_db.FORMACONTATODB.ToList(), "ID", "NOME");
    return View();

}
```

> Na View

```
@model IEnumerable<model que voce estava usando>
<div class="col-md-3">
<label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="control-label lb-pf-forma-contato">Forma de Contato</label>
<select asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" onchange="ChamarFunction(this.id)" asp-items="@ViewBag.FormaContatos" id="@Model.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-pf-forma-contato"><option value=""></option></select>
<span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasContatosViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContatoTipoViewModel.PessoaFisicaFormaContato" class="text-danger val-pf-forma-contato"></span></div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="out"></div>
```

> No javascript

```
function ChamarFunction(id) {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Controller/TipoContato',
    data: {
        'ID': id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var opts = "";
            opts += '<select id="idFormaContato" class="form-control">'
            opts += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecione</option>'
            $(data).each(function (i) {
                opts += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nome + ' </option>'
                //data[i].atributo da sua classe , qualquer coisa coisa coloque um ponto de parada no navegador e veja o objeto q está recebendo no data
            });
            opts += '</select>'
            $("#out").html(opts);
        }else{
            $("#out").html("Sem tipo de contato");   
        }

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('Erro')
    }
});
```

};

> Novamente no controller

```
public IActionResult TipoContato(int ID)// mesmo nome no método do ajax (TipoContato)
{
   var lista = _db.TipoContatoDB.Where(c => c.TipoContatoID == id).ToList();
   if(lista != null) 
   {
      return Json(lista);
   }       
   return Json(null);
}
```

> qualquer coisa comenta aí se der erro